# Can 'svn switch' be slower than 'rm -rf && svn checkout'?

Tags: performance, svn

Suppose that my working copy ~/WC/ is up to date with http://acme.com/svn-rep/**A**/.
Now i would like that same working copy be up to date with http://acme.com/svn-rep/**B**/.
I have two options:

1. svn switch http://acme.com/svn-rep/B/ ~/WC/
2. rm -rf ~/WC/ && svn co http://acme.com/svn-rep/B/ ~/WC/

Obviously, the best case of option 1 is faster than then best case of option 2. But can there be a case where for the **worst** case, option 1 is slower than the worst case than option 2?

The reason i am asking is that i am writing a bunch of scripts to automate some testing, and i will need to work on several branches within the same repository. There is a limited amount of disk space on the test machines, so i will have to reuse the same working copy.

### EDIT:

After reading the link in aix's answer below, there appears to be a third option:

- svn cleanup ~/WC/ && svn switch http://acme.com/svn-rep/B/ ~/WC/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't personally experienced this, but it would appear that there could be performance issues with `svn switch`: [Slow switch in subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514792/slow-switch-in-subversion)

It's hard to say whether `rm && svn co` would be faster or slower in those circumstances. I'd imagine this would depend on the relative performance of your local disk, network connection to the `svn` server etc.

That said, I personally would probably use `svn switch` in the first instance, and would look into alternatives only if I run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for the link which informed me about a third option. Edited my question to include this third option.